# Запись в файл структуру. Текстовый документ содержит иероглифы. Как избавиться?

Tags: c++

```
#include "File.h"
#include "People.h"

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <iostream>
using std::ofstream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(NULL, "RUS");

    Man a;
    People b;

    b.write(&a);    

    //создали файл.
    ofstream F("Текстовый файл.txt");

    if (!F.is_open()) {
        cout << "Не удаётся открыть файл.";
        return 1;
    }

    //записываем в файл
    F.write((char *)&b, sizeof b);

    F.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы записываете в бинарном режиме - что ж вы хотите? (кстати, **что** вы записываете - вы не показали, но неважно...) Хотите текст - пишите, как текст...

Comment: Структуру с 2-мя полями: имя, фамилия

Comment: Знаете, это примерно как в графе "пол" в анкете написать "паркет"... Вобщем, как пишете, то и получаете...